# how can I check the length of a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python and I want to know the number of "words"/"products" in it:

```
     print shopping_list
```

output: ['milk,cookies,apples']

now the output should be 3 but its 1 and I don't understand why :

```
    print len(shopping_list)
```

output: 1

***note*** I need it to be one string that contains those words separated by commas

Comment: You have 1 string in a list, not 3 items

Comment: The list contains **one** `string`. The commas are **not** the list separators.

Answer (score 4):

Your starting list is:

```
shopping_list = ['milk,cookies,apples']
```

This is a list which contains a single string `'milk,cookies,apples'`
You need to adjust your list so it is as below.

```
shopping_list = ['milk','cookies','apples']
```

Your code will then function as expected. This is then a list of strings that can used to calculate the length.

You can get python to split the list using the comma as an indicator of a new item.

```
shopping_list = ['milk,cookies,apples']
shopping_list = shopping_list[0].split(",")
print shopping_list
This will return 
['milk','cookies','apples']
```

Note that as the original `shopping_list` is a list we need to state that we want to first item, which is index `[0]`

```
print len(shopping_list)
```

Will now return 3.

Comment: You should also mention how to get this list from the string OP has.

Comment: I need it to be in one string . so i'm sorry I meant : how can I print the number of "products" in this list? (they need to be in one string)

Comment: @Michelle `len(yourstring.split(','))` then.

Answer (score 2):

Your List contains one string 'milk,cookies,apples'

you should insert them separately

```
list = ["milk", "cookies"] # at declaration

list.append("apples")  # adding items to the list
```

so now when you use :

```
print len(list)
```

the output is 3.

Answer (score 0):

So if your requirement is one string that has items separated by commas you could use the split(token) function to split your string, which returns a list and you can take the length of that list like so:

```
s = 'milk,cookies,apples'
len(s.split(','))          # 3
```